# jQuery Dialog Error: no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, dialog, tooltip

I created a jQuery dialog in my website to show embedded Youtube videos and it was working absolutely fine UNLESS I added jQuery Tooltip to the page. The page started showing the following error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jquery.min.js:12
2Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

Following is the order in which the source files are added:

- jquery-ui.css
- jquery.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js
- jquery.tools.min.js

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show some code, an as-small-as-possible example that shows the behaviour. If needed, use js-fiddle, but don't just past all your code here: remove unneede stufs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include jquery.min.js when you are including jquery.tools.min.js

include your source files in this order

- jquery-ui.css
- jquery.tools.min.js
- jquery.ui.min.js